# Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be such that $\limsup_{x\to 0}\limsup_{y\to 0}|f(x)-f(y)|=0$. Then $f(x)$ is Cauchy as $x\to0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be some function such that 
$$\varlimsup_{x\to 0^+}\varlimsup_{y\to0^+}\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert=0$$ then I wish to show that $f(x)$ is Cauchy as $x\to 0$. I know that we must have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\varlimsup_{y\to0}\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert=0$$ and therefore for some fixed $\varepsilon>0$, we can find $x_0>0$ such that $x<x_0$ implies that $$\varlimsup_{y\to0}\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and therefore we can find some $y_0(x)>0$ for $x<x_0$ such that $y<y_0(x)$ implies that 
$$\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\varepsilon$$
but this isn't quite strong enough to give a $z_0>0$ such that $x,y<z_0$ implies 
$$\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

What is the correct way to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: from the functional definition of $\limsup$ we have that

$$\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\sup f(0,\epsilon)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f(\epsilon)$$

where

$$\sup f(a,b):=\sup\{f(x):x\in(a,b)\}$$